# error when sending email in python: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python-3.x, sendmail

I need to send out an email in python3, below is the script and it failed with an error of:

> 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.message import EmailMessage

att1 = [u'201902260920AM.log']
msg = MIMEText("EmailOperator testing email.")
msg['Subject'] = "EmailOperator testing email."
msg['From'] = "Airflow_Notification_No_Reply@company.Com"
msg['To'] = "pasle@company.com"

msg['files'] = str(att1).encode("UTF-8")

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

What's the right way to send out an email with attachment?

Much appreciated if anyone can enlighten me here, thank you in advance.

UPDATE1: you can run the above code in python3 and you will receive the error

UPDATE2: Indeed the actual log files I want to attach would be something like this: 
`'/home/pasle/airflow/logs/pipeline_client1/send_email/2019-02-27T01:40:38.451894+00:00/1.log'`

and I need to send emails with multiple attachments, thank you for your help.

Comment: Isn't `att1` a `list` object? So that is why it is showing byte error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
att1 = [u'201902260920AM.log']
msg = MIMEText("EmailOperator testing email.")
msg['Subject'] = "EmailOperator testing email."
msg['From'] = "Airflow_Notification_No_Reply@novantas.Com"
msg['To'] = "rxie@novantas.com"

msg['files'] = att1[0].encode("utf-8")

s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
s.send_message(msg)
s.quit()
```

It should probably work.

The fact you are using `[u'ABC']` would be a one-element list of Unicode strings.

So you need to convert the list to a single Unicode string, and then convert that to `utf-8`.

**UPDATE:**

```
import smtplib
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

files = ['/home/pasle/airflow/logs/pipeline_client1/send_email/2019-02-27T01:40:38.451894+00:00/1.log',
        '/home/pasle/airflow/logs/pipeline_client1/send_email/2019-02-27T01:40:38.451894+00:00/2.log']

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'Airflow_Notification_No_Reply@novantas.com'
msg['To'] = 'rxie@novantas.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'Email operator testing email.'
message = MIMEText('Email operator testing email body text.')
msg.attach(message)

for f in files:
    with open(f, "rb") as file:
        part = MIMEApplication(
            file.read(),
            Name=basename(f)
        )
    # After the file is closed
    part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
    msg.attach(part)

gmail_sender = 'sender@gmail.com'
gmail_passwd = 'password'

server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
server.login(gmail_sender, gmail_passwd)

server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

As I looked into your problem `Attribute Error` was occurring due to not declaring `msg` as a `MIMEMultipart()` method.

Comment: Thanks. `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: Indeed the actual log files I want to attach would be something like this: `'/home/pasle/airflow/logs/pipeline_client1/send_email/2019-02-27T01:40:38.451894+00:00/1.log', and I need to send emails with multiple attachments, thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks Karikey, but as I commented earlier here, there is another error `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'`

Comment: Made some changes

Comment: Thank you, I got that working before I see your latest update, same approach.